# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf using @PathVariable results in 404 of JS

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, relative-path, thymeleaf

In my project I have all these forms associated with their IDs. So in some of my controllers I use `@PathVariable` so when the user clicks on a form name it will take them to the right one, example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/form/{formId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCid(Model model, @PathVariable Long formId){
    model.addAttribute("form", formRepository.findOne(formId));
    return "form";
}
```

However I've noticed from Firebug error messages that in these controllers, instead of looking in the `/js` folder for my static JQuery it will look in `/form/js` which obviously does not exist.

Example of how I import the JS files in my Thymeleaf views

```
<script th:src="@{js/jquery-1.11.2.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is `@PathVariable` really the issue here? This doesn't happen with the CSS files only the JS. Should I not use `@PathVariable`? Could I use `@RequestParam` to achieve the same result? What's an example?

Or is there anyway to set a global configuration of the location of my static content? I'm using Spring Boot so I basically have no configuration/xml files right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start your thymeleaf uri's with a slash `/` for it to be resolved relative to your root context, so replacing with the following should work consistently across for you:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery-1.11.2.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```